# Reason of third return statement in method

Tags: go

I’m new to Go and to practice I do some coding exercice on Exercism. I stubbled on a particular exercice in which I’m having a hard time undestanding the solution. Here’s the code:

```
// Ints defines a collection of int values
   type Ints []int

// Lists defines a collection of arrays of ints
type Lists [][]int

// Strings defines a collection of strings
type Strings []string

// Keep filters a collection of ints to only contain the members where the provided function returns true.
func (i Ints) Keep(strainer func(int) bool) (o Ints) {
    for _, v := range i {
        if strainer(v) {
            o = append(o, v)
        }
    }

    return
}

// Discard filters a collection to only contain the members where the provided function returns false.
func (i Ints) Discard(strainer func(int) bool) Ints {
    return i.Keep(func(n int) bool { return !strainer(n) })
}
```

My Problem comes with the Discard Method, I dont understand the second return statement in the curly braces since the Keep function is suppose to return a value of type Ints and not a boolean statement unless I missed something, if someone could break down the Discard function for me it would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Keep` method takes a *function as a parameter*. It expects it to be `func (int) bool` - a function taking an `int` and returning a `bool`.

When `Keep` is invoked in `Discard`, the code passes it an anonymous function with the right signature (take `int`, return `bool`). This anonymous function invokes `strainer` (which is a function passed into `Discard`) and returns its response, negated.

The idea is that `strainer` is a filter function: it tells you which elements to keep. So the implementation of `Keep` is straightforward: iterate over all elements, and keep only those for which `strainer` returns true.

`Discard` is written in a clever way using `Keep`, instead of also writing a loop like this:

```
func (i Ints) Discard(strainer func(int) bool) (o Ints) {
    for _, v := range i {
        if !strainer(v) {
            o = append(o, v)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

It instead invokes `Keep` with a function that inverts the result of `strainer`.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation Eli, I understand it now